# Generate a static HTML version of your Ionic application?

Tags: ionic-framework, static-html

I know about `ionic serve` command which enables me to test & develop my Ionic application.

But is there a command (or is it possible) to export my project as a static HTML bundle in order to view it using a browser without installing NodeJS and all other dependencies and without starting any server?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `ionic serve` actually generates a static version of the app (via gulp). Hence take a look at the `/www` folder in your ionic application. Opening `index.html` in a browser lets you view the app without having to run ionic serve in the same time.